# How to group stacked bars in barplot function

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked

i need help in grouping stacked bars in barplot function, although I think my question is somewhat 'dumb', I would really appreciate if someone could help. I created a data frame to practice:

[image]

I imported the file and processed it with this code lines:

```
teste <- read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE)
prop <- subset(teste, select = -nome)
barplot(t(as.matrix(prop)), col = rainbow(6), names.arg = teste$nome, space = 0)
```

and received the following plot:

[image]

My question is: Is there a way to group the three first bar under 'id1' only once and not repeat 'id1' for all the three bars?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you want.

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(prop)), col = rainbow(6), names.arg = c("", "id1", "", "", "id2", ""), space = 0)
```

[image: bar]

Comment: YESSS.

But I have a large quantity of data, so abou 3150 columns divided into about 15 groups. And the quantity between groups also varies (like group 1 have 100 samples and group 2 have 15 samples). Is there a way to make the group name centered?